# Use LINQ in order to select a list by matched sublist values in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class called `Item`:

```
public sealed class Item 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public sealed class Language 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a list of `Item` based on a match language.

So:

```
string currentLangCode = "EN";
List<Item> items = GetListOfItems();

// that's not correct, I need an advice here
var query = from i in items
          where ( i.Languages.Select(l=>l).Where(l=>l.Code.Equals(currentLangCode) )
          select i;
```

I want to filter a list of items if their sublist (means list of languages) contains `currentLanguage`.

How to do that using LINQ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var filtered = GetListOfItems().Where(x => x.Languages.Any(l => l.Code == currentLangCode));
```

FYI your existing solution isn't far off, all you need to do is get rid of the unnecessary `Select(...)` call and you have it i.e.

```
var filtered = from i in GetListOfItems()
               where i.Languages.Any(l => l.Code == currentLangCode)
               select i;
```